# How to install Spree commerce extensions via Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, e-commerce, spree

I recently installed spree commerce on Heroku. I want to install additional spree commerce extensions but i have no clue on  how to do that via Heroku. I am new to ruby and rails as well as Heroku.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Spree locally following this guide: https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/getting-started/installation
2. Add the extension as described here: https://github.com/spree/spree_starter#adding-new-gems
3. Push that code to GitHub and use the Heroku button